# How to get an integer from a tkinter entry box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to work out how to get a value from a tkinter entry box, and then store it as a integer. This is what I have:

```py
AnswerVar = IntVar()
AnswerBox = Entry(topFrame)
AdditionQuestionLeftSide = random.randint(0, 10)
AdditionQuestionRightSide = random.randint(0, 10)
AdditionQuestionRightSide = Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionRightSide).grid(row=0,column=0)
AdditionSign = Label(topFrame, text="+").grid(row=0,column=1)
AdditionQuestionLeftSide= Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionLeftSide).grid(row=0,column=2)
EqualsSign = Label(topFrame, text="=").grid(row=0,column=3)
AnswerBox.grid(row=0,column=4)
answerVar = AnswerBox.get()
    
root.mainloop() 
(


)
```

How can I take the input from AnswerBox, and store it in the integer variable "answer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an `IntVar` associated with the entry widget, all you need to do is get the value of that object with the `get` method:

```
int_answer = answer.get()
```

If you don't use an `IntVar`, you can get the value of the entry widget and the convert it to an integer with `int`:

```
string_answer = AnswerBox.get()
int_answer = int(string_answer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now updated the code. I assume that I don't need a button, and the value is entered when the code is run. Just wondering as according to the debugger, the value of answerVar is "

Comment: @DanielColthart: the value will be blank until the user has a chance to enter something. _after_ they enter data, you can call the `get()` method. That typically means you have a button, or a binding somewhere that calls the method.

Comment: Ok thank you...I understand now...the code skips past it as nothing is entered and the user is actually entering code in the loop

Comment: @DanielColthart: I don't know what you mean by "skips past it" -- tkinter won't skip any code unless you tell it to. The `get()` method simply returns what is currently in the widget. If you call it immediately after creating the widget there will be nothing in it.

Comment: Ah ok...it seems like it moved past it as there was nothing in it. I have now set up an event that activates the get function..and all seems to be working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from an Entry widget in tkinter you call the `get()` method on the widget. This will return the widget's value.

So you would do `answer = AnswerBox.get()`