# Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter GUI program python

Tags: python, tkinter

Write a GUI program that converts Celsius temperatures to Fahrenheit temperatures. The user should be able to enter a Celsius temperature, click a button, then see the equivalent Fahrenheit temperature. Use the following formula to make the conversion:

F= (9/5)C+32

F is the Fahrenheit temperature, and C is the Celsius temperature.

Here's what I've got but when I run it nothing happens:

```
#import
#main function
from tkinter import *
def main():
    root=Tk()

    root.title("Some GUI")
    root.geometry("400x700")
    #someothersting=""
    someotherstring=""
    #enter Celcius
    L1=Label(root,text="Enter a Celcius temperature.")
    E1=Entry(root,textvariable=someotherstring)
    somebutton=Button(root, text="Total", command=lambda: convert(E1.get()))

    somebutton.pack()
    E1.pack()
    L1.pack()
    root.mainloop()#main loop


#convert Celcius to Fahrenheit
def convert(somestring):
    if somestring != "":    
        cel=int(somestring)
        far=(9/5*(cel))+32
        print(far)
```

Comment: you can't expect others to fully write you the code, ask here for issues/errors

Comment: You never call the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the lack of `main()`.

You should add `main()` to the very end of your code. That said you really don't need the `main()` function to begin with.

You are trying to assign a string as a text-variable in the entry field and this wont do anything. If you wish to use the `textvariable` argument then you need to use something like `StringVar()` or `IntVar()`. We don't need anything like that here. We can simple use the `entry.get()` method within your `convert` function.

By moving this `get()` method to the `convert` function we can remove the lambda from your button command. Simply do `command=convert`.

With those changes you can have something simple like the below.

```
from tkinter import *


def convert():
    x = entry.get()
    if x != "":    
        cel=int(x)
        far=(9/5*(cel))+32
        print(far)

root=Tk()
root.title("Some GUI")
root.geometry("400x700")

Button(root, text="Total", command=convert).pack()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
Label(root,text="Enter a Celcius temperature.").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

## 1. You can create the GUI for the program using Python's GUI toolkits. You can use TKinter for a start. Must also contain an entry box where you will put the Celsius data.

## 2. After creating the GUI, just get the value from that box, then use your formula to calculate the fahrenheit equivalent. you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171005/how-to-get-an-integer-from-a-tkinter-entry-box) tutorial on how to get the data from an entry box.

E.G :

```
 string_answer = entryBox.get()
 celsius = int(string_answer)
 fahrenheit = (9/5)celsius + 32
```

## 3. Display the data to your GUI interface.

Comment: And you can't expect other people to write the code for you, sir. You should create it yourself and we will try our best to help you with any problems regarding the program :)