# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Entry'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm learning python and working on project that generate a password but i got a problem with tkinter

I'm using Python3.

My code:

```
import random
from cgitb import grey
from decimal import DefaultContext
from operator import le
from tkinter import *
from turtle import color, width


window = Tk()
window.title("IDK")
window.configure(bg='grey')
window.geometry("500x500")
window.geometry()


label_title=Label(window, width=6, text="Lenght:", font=(30), bg='#0000FF')
label_title.place(x=0,y=120) 
len_Entry= Entry(window, bd =5)
len_Entry.place(x=120,y=120)

def yeso():
    DefaultLabel = Label(window, text="Default: Yes", font=50)
    DefaultLabel.place(x=290,y=200)
    lower_case = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    upper_case = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    num = "0123456789"
    Symbols = "[]{}#()*;._-"
    ans = upper_case + lower_case + num + Symbols
    lenght = str(len_Entry)
    password = "".join(random.sample(ans , len_Entry))
    print(password)


def noo():
    DefaultLabel = Label(window, text="Default: No  ", font=50)
    DefaultLabel.place(x=290,y=200)
    lower_case = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    upper_case = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    num = "0123456789"
    ans2 = upper_case + lower_case + num
    lenght = len_Entry
    password = "".join(random.sample(ans2 , lenght))
    print(password)

Symboletxt = Label(window,width=8, text="Symboles:", font=(30), bg='#0000FF')
Symboletxt.place(x=0,y=200)
my_button = Button(window, text="Yes", bg='#00FF00',command=yeso)
my_button.place(x=120, y=200)
my2_button = Button(window, text="No", bg='#ff0000',command=noo)
my2_button.place(x=180, y=200)



window.mainloop()
```

The Error :
if not 0 <= k <= n:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Entry'

Comment: Apparently somewhere your code uses an Entry where an int is expected. Find out where that is (hint: the error traceback tells you) and change the code so that an int is used instead of an Entry.

Comment: Another hint: `int(<Entry>.get())` get the data from the entry as an `int`eger.

Comment: Look at this call:  `random.sample(ans , len_Entry)`  The second argument should be an integer.  But it's not.  It's an instance of class `Entry`.  Change it to an integer.

Comment: `lenght = str(len_Entry)` should become `lenght = int(len_Entry.get())` in both functions `yeso()` and `noo()` and here `password = "".join(random.sample(ans , len_Entry))` you apparently wanted to place `lenght` instead of `len_Entry`

Comment: Yes, you can also use some error catching to make sure the user is giving the right type. ```if type(eval(len_Entry.get())) != int: #WRONG TYPE```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an integer from a tkinter entry box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171005/how-to-get-an-integer-from-a-tkinter-entry-box)